# envify in react.js doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to node.js and react.js.
I recently learn react.js and follow the instruction on react.js [offical page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) and try to use production mode.
So i start with the code in main.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

and browserify it

```
$ browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] -t [ envify --NODE_ENV production  ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

But envify seems not work. The result bundle code still contain

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Is something wrong? I 've tried to set `process.env.NODE_ENV='production'` in the main.js. But it doesnt work. can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the NODE_ENV variable in the shell instead.

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] -t envify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because you are only running `envify` on *your own* files. To make `browserify` to apply it to all modules (including React's code), use `-g` (aka global transform) instead of `-t`:

```
$ browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] -g [ envify --NODE_ENV production ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

See [browserify's manual](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) for the details.